# ExtJs - How to fetch elements from childEls

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm using the snippet bellow to add some HTML elements to the top of a FormPanel:

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    itemId: 'form-top',
    cls: 'form-top-items',
    renderTpl: [
        '<div id="{id}-formHelp" class="form-help">',
            '<span class="form-help-text">{helpText}</span>',
        '</div>'
    ],
    renderData: {
        helpText: __("Os campos com * são de preenchimento obrigatório.")
    },
    childEls: [
        {name: 'formHelp', itemId: 'form-help'}
    ]
}
```

But once the component is rendered, I can't fetch any child items.

I'm expecting a way to access the `formHelp` item somehow, but can't find it anyway bellow the `form-top` component.

Comment: give it an `id` to the `component` then try to get all objects from the console `Ext.getCmp('id')`. Do you see `childEls` in there?

Comment: I can get the component from the console. And I can list the `childEls` config. But `component.formHelp` is returning `null` instead of my childEl.

Comment: try this `{name: 'formHelp', id: 'form-help'}` and use getCmp to access `Ext.getCmp('form-help')`. In document, as they specified, itemId combination of the main component id.

Comment: If I set childEls just `childEls: [ 'formHelp' ]` this it works fine. Seens like a bug to me.

Comment: no, I think you have misunderstood something. When you check the document, `If the array member is a string, it is equivalent to { name: m, itemId: m }` so, if you set only a string, both name and itemId will be same.

Comment: Sure, but didn't work for me with an object.
I'll have some testes to check if it happens frequently (using Ext 4.2).

Answer (score 1):

The `itemId` must match the portion of your child el's id that comes after `{id}-`.

You have two options:

- Change your `itemId` to `'formHelp'`

OR

- change your div to `<div id="{id}-form-help" class="form-help">`